# Expected root reducer function. Instead received: undefined error in react native application

Tags: react-native

I am building a react native app but I get following error `Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'`

I have a index.js file which exports the Reducers.

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const Reducers = combineReducers();

export default Reducers;
```

In the App.js file I create a store `const store = createStore(rootReducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));`

But when I run `expo start` I get the above error. I am exporting a reducer function right ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any reducer to your `combineReducers()`.
Please add two or more reducer to combineReducers function.
Like

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  appReducer: appReducer,
  authReducer: authReducer,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are exporting a reducer function. However, you are not using the [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) function correctly:

> The combineReducers helper function turns an object whose values are different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can pass to createStore.

The `combineReducers` function expects a single argument:

> An object whose values correspond to different reducing functions that
> need to be combined into one.

You are calling `combineReducers` without any arguments, so the first argument becomes `undefined`, which is why you are getting `Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'`.
Here is a toy example of how it can be used:

```
export default function firstReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        // do something based on the action.type
        default:
            // default case just returns the state
            return state;
    }
}

export default function secondReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        // do something based on the action.type
        default:
            // default case just returns the state
            return state;
    }
}

rootReducer = combineReducers({first: firstReducer, second: secondReducer})
// This would produce the following state object
{
    first: {
        // state managed by firstReducer
    },
    second: {
        // state managed by secondReducer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case, the problem was the wrong import of reducer.
If you wrote the rootReducer in reducers.js as the following

```
export function rootReducer() {
    ...
}
```

Please use it when you create a store like this.

```
import { rootReducer } from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducers);
```

But if you created the rootReducer like this

```
export default function rootReducer() {
    ...
}
```

You should import it without braces.

```
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducers);
```